# AirWatch SDK Integration with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, mdm, native-code, airwatch

I'm working on a project using sencha touch 2.3, and its a project requirement to integrate it using AirWatch SDK. I googled it out but nothing found anything that might clear me the confusion to integrate it with Phonegap (sencha touch). [AirWatch](http://www.air-watch.com/) Provides a Iphone iOS SDK and sample code which is fully native example to test AirWatch.

I need to know is their any possibility that might help me out to integrate phonegap with AirWatch Native code.

Might this link also help to tells the possibility [click here](http://www.air-watch.com/differentiators/enterprise-integration/apis) but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you made any progress?  Could you please share what you've been able to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

AirWatch has released their official plugin for the cordova. You can check it out here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/airwatch-sdk-plugin

I have tested it to work with ioninc as well for those who are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Airwatch ACE for public apps and Airwatch App wrapping for internal apps using airwatch admin console.

I have pushed Hybrid internal Apps (having cordova) with app wrapping on Airwatch.

SDK requires lots of coding on ios/android side. If you are comfortable with integrating your cordova code with ios or android then you can go ahead with Airwatch SDK option.

Comment: Sorry to ask but, how do you get the sdk and where?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, Airwatch has an app wrapping functionality. I'm also having some difficulties when integrating hybrid function with AW. For android, apk is enough. For ios, make sure you upload the .p12 certificates and the bundle id matches.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching the web for Cordova Plugin for Air Watch and came across your post.

If Air Watch doesn't provide a plugin, and instead offers an SDK, then you can write your own native plugin to integrate with Air Watch through their SDK.

I just wrote a plugin for another native functionality and it's not difficult, once you learn how to do it. :-)

There is a [nice tutorial on Cordova 3](http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/)

It doesn't cover plugins and unfortunately, the docs are not that clear. If you wish to go this route, I can provide you the details on how to create and install a plugin.

Comment: i heard that airwatch provide ios sdk but didn't find any link to douwnload that or any brief information read more on this :(